# Image shrinking when window is resized

Tags: css

How can I get the image to shrink when the size of the window gets smaller without making the image stretched funny. I want the size of the image to auto adjust to make it look normal at all sizes.

```
.frontpage{
  background: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/168/apple-iphone-laptop-notebook.jpg');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
min-height:1000px;
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/zuf63jft/1/)

Comment: tried something other than `px` like.. `vh`? [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, use `background-size: cover`:

```
.frontpage{
  background: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/168/apple-iphone-laptop-notebook.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
min-height:1000px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vLn0zqsf/)

Comment: This is pretty much the closest thing to what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the value [`contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images#contain) for `background-size`, it will adjust the background to be contained within the bounds of the container

```css
div {
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/g/256/256);
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border:1px solid lime;
}

.first {
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
}

.second {
  width:256px;
  height:60px;
}

.third {
  width:200px;
  height:350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just try following style

```
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
```

This will make the background image width 100%, and height will get auto with correct ratio.

You also can try other options like

```
background-size: contain;
```

or

```
background-size: cover;
```